# How to get a list of compatible vm sizes for deploy in the same cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-management-api

I have a single cloud service in Azure that contains one VM. I would like to deploy another virtual machine.

What is the api to get a list of compatible vm sizes for deploy in the same cloud service?

I don't want to have the following exception:

`Hyak.Common.CloudException: Compute.CannotUpgradeDeploymentToNewRoleSize : Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size 'Standard_D4' may not be available in the resources supporting the existing deployment. ..`

Answer (score 0):

@ivan_petrushenko, I think the API you want to get a list of compatible vm sizes for deploy in the same cloud service is the one of the list below.

1. [List available VM sizes in an availability set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269438.aspx)
2. [List available VM sizes in a region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269440.aspx)
3. [List all available virtual machine sizes for resizing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269441.aspx)

And according to the [troubleshooting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-restart-resize-error-troubleshooting/#issue-error-when-resizing-an-existing-vm) for resizing an existing VM, you can try to stop the VM first, then to start to resize the VM.

As references, there is a similar [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/707026/creating-vm-fail-if-vm-type-is-different-than-other-vms-in-the-virtual-network) from ServerFault that the answerer has a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/11/11/azure-a-series-d-series-and-g-series-consistent-performances-and-size-change-considerations/) introduced the VM size change considerations. Meanwhile, a [blog](https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2015/10/11/azure-virtual-machine-resizing-consideration/) from a MS partner shows the tables about all the resizing configuration paths.

---

**Update**:
The section [`Allocation scenario: Resize a VM or add VMs or role instances to an existing cloud service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-allocation-failure/#allocation-scenario-resize-a-vm-or-add-vms-or-role-instances-to-an-existing-cloud-service) explained your issue.